# Check user email status before page loads

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I'm using an unless spacebar function to check if a user has verified their email address. In production, I assume due to a delay, the screen displays this notice and then changes after a second if the email has been verified. Is there a way to slow down the page load so the users email status is checked before the page loads?

```
<template name="mainLayout">

        {{#unless currentUser.emails.[0].verified}}
            <p class="alert alert-warning text-center">We have sent you an email to verify your email address. All users must confirm their email address to access the BHR platform.</p>

        {{else}}

        <div id="content" class="content">
            <div class="container">
                {{>Template.dynamic template=main}}     
            </div>      
        </div>

        {{/unless}}

    </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay come because the first time the template is rendered the `Meteor.user()` object has not yet been fully loaded. Then it loads and reactively the sections get swapped.

You need to show a loading screen/spinner while the user object is loading. How you do this will depend on what router you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what Michael was suggesting. Wrap you templates in:

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}

{{/if}}
```